# Spring security rest plugin for neo4j database

Tags: grails, spring-security, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am using neo4j database in my grails application,how to configure spring security rest plugin for neo4j database.
I am using SDN(spring-data-neo4j),not grails plugin for neo4j.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? what have you tried so far?

Comment: grails plugin for spring security rest works for mysql database well,i want to use it with neo4j database.

Comment: Googling found this: http://blog.vergiss-blackjack.de/2010/04/spring-security-authentication-with-a-neo4j-backend/

Comment: @MichaelHunger Thanks,but i have solved this issue,i successfully integrated spring-security-rest plugin in my grails application and connected with neo4j through SDN.